# Creating a meta model using UML convention and creating a data model out of it

Tags: uml, data-extraction, metamodel

Sorry if the question sounds too vague. I will improve based on your feedback.

I have managed to prepare a UML model of a problem domain. This is essentially a class diagram describing class attributes and aggregation relationships amongst classes. Intention now is to fill data.

For example, class-A aggregates N instances of Class-B. I would like to create a data model that has data for one instance Class-A and 5 instances of Class-B.

Basically, data pertaining to this meta model is available in a document (e.g. xls, framemaker) and it should be possible to read the source and populate the data model.

Are there tools that will let me create this data model? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to creates your database model from our UML model.

You can use the UML model and then add a code generator to generate the database then finally reverse it with a database modeling tool such as erwin.

Another approach is to use the database modeling profile inside your UML  model. It means that ypu model and add database stereotype related to java ORM. 
Both works pretty well.

Comment: Hi UML Guru. The first option is probably what I want to do. I presume the code generator should be aware of the schema. Are there code generation tools for such code generators? I have to admit my knowledge in these areas does not go beyond textbook C++.

Comment: You have many open source code generator for Java but I don t know for C++ which is not my expertize..